# ¿Como agregar animacion a mis controles de wpf con Material design?

Tags: wpf, material-design

Hola Muy Buenas Noches tengo la siguiente consulta
Estoy trabajando las interfaces de mi proyecto con `WPF` y Material `Design` en `C#`.
Mi pregunta es la siguiente Como puedo agregar animación a los controles que tiene mi formulario y que se ejecute cuando la ventana se abre recién empece a utilizar Material Design y no conosco muy bien que animación tiene o como utilizarlas..

Gracias por su atención y tiempo.

Comment: Dale una mirada a [mahapps](http://mahapps.com/)

Comment: su efecto me funciona cuando utilizo Window.xaml pero estoy utilizando UserControl.xaml y no me funciona por eso queria que me ayuden a como hacerlo con material design grasias

Comment: o como aplicar el efecto de mahapps pero en los UserControl

Answer (score 0):

Digamos que tenemos dos UserControls (UC_1 Y UC_2). En el UC_1 agregas un Grid en donde 
mostraras el UC_2.

Código para el UC_1

XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="GridTerciario"/>
```

Code-Behind en donde esta el Incializador agregas

```
GridTerciario.Children.Add( new UC_2());
```

Código para el UC_2

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <materialDesign:TransitioningContent OpeningEffect="{materialDesign:TransitionEffect SlideInFromRight, Duration=0:0:0.8}">
    </materialDesign:TransitioningContent>
</Grid>
```

Nota: Puedes ver la [documentación](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Transitions), ahí te describen otras transiciones.